# Mongoose: update an array item from its index, whose value is given by a variable

Tags: mongoose

In order to modify the second film of Kubrick in the collection named `cinema` one can use the following request:

```
db.cinema.update({director: "Kubrick"}, {$set : {"films.1" : "2001"}})
```

But what if the index is variable instead of necessarily being 1?

I've tried various uses of the `$` symbol but none of them works.

I don't want to change the structure of the collection.

I would like to avoid getting the whole array, modifying it and then updating it in the collection (which is quite heavy and probably bad for the performance).

Comment: do you mean external variable? then try {$set : {` films.${variable name}` : "2001"}}

Comment: Please add sample collections, and the expected result.

Comment: @turivishal: it unfortunately doesn't compile ("Property assignment expected")

Comment: Then you are not passing the proper assignment.